# Python filter warnings to hide repetitions, even if the message changes

Tags: python, event-handling, warnings

The documentation for the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) module states that the default action is:

> print the first occurrence of matching warnings for each location (module + line number) where the warning is issued.

but it stays evasive about which part of the message defines a "match". When I run the following code, it repeats each warning that has a different message, even if the *location* is identical.

```py
import warnings

for i in range(3):
    warnings.warn("Warning 1: fixed message")
    warnings.warn("Warning 2: variable message #%d" % i)
```

```
./test_repeated_warnings.py:8: UserWarning: Warning 1: fixed message
  warnings.warn("Warning 1: fixed message")
./test_repeated_warnings.py:9: UserWarning: Warning 2: variable message #0
  warnings.warn("Warning 2: variable message #%d" % i)
./test_repeated_warnings.py:9: UserWarning: Warning 2: variable message #1
  warnings.warn("Warning 2: variable message #%d" % i)
./test_repeated_warnings.py:9: UserWarning: Warning 2: variable message #2
  warnings.warn("Warning 2: variable message #%d" % i)
```

How do you hide repetitions of a warning for a specific location, whatever the message?

I tried to explicitly set a filter, but it did not have any effect:

```py
warnings.filterwarnings('once', '^Warning 2.*', UserWarning)
```

Comment: "matching warnings" means the entire text must match exactly. Since `i` changes each time, they're not duplicates. So don't put any dynamic information in the message if you want them to be merged.